# Getting out of a rut when your sick and dying

Tags: meditation-recommendation, death, meditation-teachers

What are the teachings and books that are good for inspiring  the sick and soon to be dying? If your brain is getting eaten away, what are the best practices for that? Anyone know of any Doctors who would understand all this insight meditation stuff? Doctors often seem to me far too  smart to be wise.

Comment: You might find some answers to these topics helpful: [What do you do to prepare for death?](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/28418/254), and, [Buddhism and terminal illness](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/q/12050/254)

Answer (score 1):

Buddha once visited an infirmary for monks and advised to practice satipattana (Maha Satipattana Sutta, Deega Nikaya)

Bojjangha Sutta is well known to be contemplated by monks who are sick and known to have already practiced dhamma (hence being able to cultivate them when recited to them)

There is an instance where Nakula pitha (anagami) visits Buddha and related he's sick where Buddha reminds him it's the body that gets sick and not the mind.

There is an instance Arhat Maha Sariputta visits a dying person who has proper faith in Buddha, Dhamma and Sangha. The priest asks the dying person to think of different realms of birth, starting from animals all the way to brahma realms.

I hope these help.

Answer (score 0):

I had been trying to locate a video that I watched recently. It was about terminally ill patients who were being encouraged to read the Bardo Thodol (The Tibetan Book of the Dead) with the hope that they could retain the information therein and use it as a guide to liberate oneself from the cycle of rebirth during the bardo phase of consciousness. It was quite fascinating. I will keep searching for it. In the meantime maybe read the book [here](https://holybooks-lichtenbergpress.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/The-Tibetan-Book-of-the-Dead.pdf) or listen to an audio version [here](https://youtu.be/E1MZwriqVvw).

Also, [this guy](https://youtu.be/hBl5v2WGqrI) explains the book quite well in his teaching.